# How to change the order of number digits?

Tags: align, right-to-left

[image]

How can I change text to be left aligned?

So that, instead of 1.4 it will show 4.1.

Comment: *Alignment* is completely different from *numbering*. Can you be more clear in your requirement?

Comment: It seems that all the numbers are written in the opposite direction. I need to change that.

Comment: But this is not normal. The reason is in your document, which we don't know.

Comment: You could have at least used the site search (-1).

Comment: @HenriMenke The question is about why the the section num,bering is swapped? Not about indentation?

Comment: @ Johannes_B that's right. I can't find in my document where this is defined or how to change it.

Comment: Please show us a minimal compilable code example that reproduces your problem.

Comment: http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/ <- the link contains a simple algorithm that helps you in finding the cause easily.

Comment: @Werner: I think the O.P. confused the order of the digits/numbers with 'alignment' in his way of expressing it. Of course, 'alignment' means a different concept in TeX etc.

Comment: There's no way this question is a duplicate of the one mentioned... (Although it might be put on hold as unclear.) The OP is using alignment in the sense of LTR and RTL. But how he's ended up with the output shown can't be determined without code.

Comment: If this question is a duplicate, then it's one of another question, but not about indentation

Comment: Oncce you updated the question, it will be reopened.